# img to mesh in blender?

Tags: mesh, image, text-object, fcurves, svg

I have to create 3d text(mesh) from this image in blender, in order to create and 3d print a sign:

[image: 1]

But how can I convert the text in the image into a curve/mesh?

Comment: You cannot convert a pixelated image to a 3D mesh. If you would like to use an image as a source to be able to have curves and elements usable in 3D, you will need to use a vector image format, such as .svg. Once you have a .svg, you can import it in Blender, and you'll be able to redefine curves and points to help you recreate the text you would like to have.

EDIT :
If you absolutely need to use this .png image, import it as a background reference, and model the text on top of it. Otherwise you can find the exact font of your image and use it into blender to "write" the text as 3D mesh

Comment: can i turn a png into an svg using gimp or inkscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to rebuild it from scratch than try to convert it to mesh. It looks like the font is the [Helvetica Ultra Compressed](https://fontsgeek.com/fonts/helvetica-ultra-compressed) which is free. Once installed, create a text object, in *Edit* mode type the text, convert to mesh and, in *Edit* mode, lean it with the *Shear* tool (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>), etc, it should be pretty quick:

[image]

Comment: thank you, at least I managed to get something decent

Comment: There'd no reason you can't rrplicate the exact same shape actually, the kind of wave behind the font is pretty easy to model as well